# Como capturar erro do mysql (duplicate entry) e exibir uma mensagem na tela para o usuário, usando o codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Como capturar o erro do mysql (duplicate entry) e exibir uma mensagem na tela para o usuário, usando o codeigniter?

> Error Number: 1062
>
> Duplicate entry '123456' for key 'processo'
>
> INSERT INTO `processo` (`nprocesso`)
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/aplicacao/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução para esse problema é pegar o sqlstate e verificar se ele é `1062` (Duplicate entry). Use o método [`error()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html) em caso de falha ele retorna um array com o código e a descrição do erro.

Seu código deve ser algo como:

```
$msg = '';
if(!$this->db->query('INSERT....')){
   $error = $this->db->error();
   if($error['code'] == 1062){
      $msg = 'Registro duplicado';
   }
}
```

Para que o CI não exiba essa mensagem de erro gigante você pode desabilitar isso via arquivo de configuração [application/config/database.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/database.php) mudando a seguinte configuração para `false`.

Antes/original:

```
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production')
```

Depois:

```
'db_debug' => false
```

Também possível fazer isso em trechos especificos via código, basta alterar o valor da propriedade [`db_debug`](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_driver.php#L175)

```
$msg = '';
$this->db->db_debug = false;
if(!$this->db->query('INSERT....')){
   $error = $this->db->error();
   if($error['code'] == 1062){
      $msg = 'Registro duplicado';
   }
}
$this->db->db_debug = true;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas não funcionou, continua aparecendo "A Database Error Occurred", estou usando mysql. 

Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry '123456' for key 'processo'

INSERT INTO processo (nprocesso)

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/aplicacao/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: @Ramiro a mensagem de erro aparece ainda pq seu ambiante está configurado como dev, quando mudar para produção não sera exibido. Tem uma forma de desligar isso via código, posso complementar isso na resposta.

Comment: pode sim, por favor.

Comment: @Ramiro editei a respostas.

Comment: Depois que você falou eu consegui. Muito obrigado!